# Update ACF fields in Wordpress admin using Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem that I've been trying to solve for some time now. It seems to me that the task is relevant for those who use ACF and want to substitute fields from one post to another. Somebody may be interested in helping solve this problem, or solved it before.

There are ACF fields that need to be updated programmatically - substitute fields from another record without reloading the page, i.e. using ajax in the admin.

What is done:
1.Connect ajax to admin - functions.php

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-acf', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/ajax-acf.js', array( 'jquery' ), time(), true );
} );
```

2.Run jquery when input button is clicked (receive "ok" response) - i use button from ACF Extended plugin.

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
  $ ('.acf-field-64647e4980e03').click( function(){
    
    var input = $(this);
    
    $.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url : ajaxurl,
      data:{
        action:'my_acf_update',
        post_id: $_POST['post_id']
        
      },
      success : function( data ) {
        
        alert( data );
      }
    })
  } ); 
} );
```

**The following hook does not work - only "ok0" is returned in the popup**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_acf_update', function(){
  // Get post id
  $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

  // Get id another post from the relation field
  $another_post_id = get_field('Blocks-FirstSlide-copyBlock', $post_id );
   
  // Getting data
  $source_fields = get_fields($another_post_id ); 

  // Update fields in this post
  foreach ($source_fields as $field_name => $field_value) {
  update_field($field_name, $field_value, $post_id);
  }
    
  update_field( 'Blocks-FirstSlide-copyBlock', $another_post_id, $post_id );
    
  echo 'ok';
  wp_die;
});
```

*Also a have hook that solves the problem but with a reboot (when i saving the post). In this case, the true/false field is also manages hook:*

```
// Substitution of field values
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

  // Checking if substitution is needed
  $acf_value = get_field('Blocks-FirstSlide-update', $post_id);
   if ($acf_value == true) {
      
  // Get id another post from the relation field
  $another_post_id = get_field('Blocks-FirstSlide-copyBlock', $post_id );
   
  // Getting data
  $source_fields = get_fields($another_post_id ); 

  // Update fields in this post
  foreach ($source_fields as $field_name => $field_value) {
  update_field($field_name, $field_value, $post_id);
  }
    
  update_field( 'Blocks-FirstSlide-copyBlock', $another_post_id, $post_id );
  }
}
```